# Put all the properties or only the properties that I'm going to update?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api with latest sdk, .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have this put method on an `ApiController`:

```
public void Put(HttpRequestMessage request, int userId, User user)
{
}
```

If an `User` has a lot of properties like name, birthday, address, country, etc. And I want to update only his/her address.

What do I have to sent from the client to the Web Api? An user instance only with his name?

This is a JSON example: `{"UserAddress":"Ugly street, 1"}`.

But, maybe, I can't do that because some of `Users` properties can't be null, (like his/her Age, because it's `int Age { get; set; }`.

Instead of putting an `User` instance, I could send all the properties that I'm going to update in `Url`, but I think this could be a mess.

Comment: For that you can do two things. first - Make your all properties nullable. OR second option is - In your model's constructor assign default value to all the properties as per their datatype. Then you can pass json like this - `{"UserAddress":"Ugly street, 1"}`

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Thanks for your comment. I thought to make all properties nullable but I've asked this question to see if there is a better approach.

Comment: In one of our project we have used the 2nd approach for our wcf service which was used by iPhone team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of `PUT` say that you must specify the complete current state of the resource. If you don't want to do that, you should be using either POST or PATCH to update your resource.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
public class AddressController : ApiController
{
    [Route("users/userId/address")]
    public void Put(int userId, Address address)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if `User` class has twenty properties, do I need to do that for each one?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to get an `User` from Web Api, update the properties on it, and put it to Web Api.

Steps:

1. Get an `User` from Web Api.
2. Update that `User` with new properties' values.
3. Put that `User` to Web Api.

This is the more generic solution. Here, we can change one or more properties and we don't need to add a method for each property and without the need to have nullable properties.